# String, ask and store

Tags: c, string

I can't figure out how to save a user input character string.

I want to ask the user for two separate string variables (a word) and store them for later use as `reference` and `query` variables. I thought of using the `scanf` to obtain the user input and `%s` for storing the variables.

I either get segmentation fault or wrong output depending on how I modify the code. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{

  char *reference, *query;

  printf("\n Enter reference genome file name:  ");
  scanf("%s", reference);

  printf("\n Enter sequence query file name:  ");
  scanf("%s", query);

  printf("\n\n Reference file used was: %s\n", reference);
  printf("Query sequence file used was: %s\n", query);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having a `char*` you should allocate with `char[]` (array of characters).

Declare your strings like this:

```
char reference[80];
char query[80];
```

This way, the computer knows how much space to save for the strings. That's why you were getting segmentation faults before, because you had a pointer to point to the beginning of a string, but no memory to store it.

I changed the code to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char reference[80];
    char query[80];

    printf("\nEnter reference genome file name:  ");
    scanf("%s", reference);

    printf("\nEnter sequence query file name:  ");
    scanf("%s", query);

    printf("\nReference file used was: %s\n"
           "Query sequence file used was: %s\n", reference, query);

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled with `gcc` and a sample run:

```
Enter reference genome file name:  file1.txt

Enter sequence query file name:  file2.txt

Reference file used was: file1.txt
Query sequence file used was: file2.txt
```

Comment: When I do this I get incorrect parsing, meaning, that the name it prints for the reference file is mixed with the query file name. Also, I get segmentation fault:

Comment: Thanks! Do you also get this warning when compiling with gcc? I get this warnings for both reference and query variables... `warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char **' [-Wformat] scanf("%s", reference);`

Comment: I am not able to get that warning with `-Wall` or `-Wformat`. I'm using a kinda old version, 4.2.1.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Is't %s pointing to a char type? Why would the storing variables `reference` and `query` char ** type?...do you know?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. To read a string, we use `%s` and then put the string variable into the `scanf`, like this example: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf

Comment: This answer suggests to replace one problem with another, which is bad. Don't use `scanf()`. Just don't use it. It's evil. It's insecure. It's quirky. It's counter-intuitive. Use `fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
char *reference, *query;
```

You have not allocated any storage for the strings.  You could do it this way:

```
char reference[100], query[100];
```

This assumes you know in advance the maximum input size, and you will need to take additional steps to make sure you don't overflow the buffers, such as by telling scanf the maximum size:

```
scanf("%99s", reference);
```

You can check the return value to see if the user typed too much, so you know if it gets truncated.

Comment: What if I don't know the input size?

Comment: Ok, this seemed to work, but how come I get a Warning when compiling for both reference and query variables: `warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char **' [-Wformat]
        scanf("%s", reference);`

Comment: John: please don't answer obvious duplicates, vote for closure instead.

Comment: @bretonics: you need to **think** about the code you are using instead of blindly copy-pasting.

Comment: @H2CO3: I actually tried to search for a good duplicate for this one but came up short ("char*" doesn't work very well in Google).  Anyway, I voted to close now, and surely wish I hadn't answered.  ;-)